# Async/Await in Redux

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, redux, redux-thunk

So, I have a function, which convert images to base64. This function is asynchronous, and it converts 4 images with the help of Promise.all(), and then I return object with received strings. So, I export async function. Here is the code:

```
import IMAC from '../assets/Images/devices/mac_monitor.png';
import MACBOOK from '../assets/Images/devices/macbook_pro.png';
import IPHONE_8 from '../assets/Images/devices/iphone_8.png';
import MSI_LAPTOP from '../assets/Images/devices/msi_laptop.png';

function loadImage(img) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        toDataURL(img, function (dataUrl) {
            resolve(dataUrl);
        })
    });
}

function toDataURL(url, callback) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            callback(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.send();
}

const IMAC_IMG_BASE64 = loadImage(IMAC);
const MACBOOK_IMG_BASE64 = loadImage(MACBOOK);
const MSI_IMG_BASE64 = loadImage(MSI_LAPTOP);
const PHONE_IMG_BASE64 = loadImage(IPHONE_8);

export async function loadAllImages() {
    const result = await Promise.all([IMAC_IMG_BASE64, MACBOOK_IMG_BASE64, MSI_IMG_BASE64, PHONE_IMG_BASE64]);
    return [
        {
            id: 0,
            device: "Apple iMac",
            image: result[0],
            styles: {
                carousel_item: {
                    width: "41.6vw",
                    height: "auto",
                    top: "-4.095vw",
                    left: "-0.13vw"
                },
                carousel: {
                    height: "38vw",
                    margin: "50px 0"
                },
                device: {
                    width: "46.5vw",
                    height: "38vw",
                    marginLeft: "-23.25vw"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            device: "Apple Macbook Pro",
            image: result[1],
            styles: {
                carousel_item: {
                    width: "37vw",
                    height: "auto",
                    top: "-4.4vw",
                    left: ".6vw"
                },
                carousel: {
                    height: "38vw",
                    margin: "50px 0"
                },
                device: {
                    width: "55vw",
                    height: "30vw",
                    marginLeft: "-27.5vw"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            device: "MSI GP72VR 7RFX",
            image: result[2],
            styles: {
                carousel_item: {
                    width: "35vw",
                    height: "auto",
                    top: "-5.8vw",
                    left: ".5vw"
                },
                carousel: {
                    height: "38vw",
                    margin: "50px 0"
                },
                device: {
                    width: "50vw",
                    height: "34vw",
                    marginLeft: "-25vw"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            device: "Iphone 8",
            image: result[3],
            styles: {
                carousel_item: {
                    width: "14vw",
                    height: "auto",
                    top: "-8.2vw",
                    left: "0"
                },
                carousel: {
                    height: "38vw",
                    margin: "50px 0"
                },
                device: {
                    width: "17.7vw",
                    height: "34vw",
                    marginLeft: "-8.85vw"
                }
            }
        },
    ];
}
```

Then, I have this action creator, which is async, where I received data from this function (loadAllImages()), and then I call dispatch (p.s. - I am using redux-thunk)

```
export const loadConfigs = () => async dispatch => {
 const data = await loadAllImages();
 dispatch({type: "LOAD_DATA", payload: data});
};
```

Also, I have reducer, where I return payload with the object, received from the called dispatch

```
export default (sliderConfig = null, action) => {
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch(type){
        case "LOAD_DATA":
            return payload;
    }

    return sliderConfig;
}
```

Inside the main container App.js, I call this AC inside the componentDidMount()
(Don't look at fetchUser(), it does not matter in this context)

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser();
        this.props.loadConfigs();
    }
```

And, then I have component, where I am using this data, which asynchronously received from the AC. (Do not look at appDesign(), it does not matter in this context)

```
import React, {Component, PureComponent} from 'react';
import appDesign from '../../../decorators/scroll_resize_decorator';
import Slider from './Slider';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../../actions';

//Hint: Use container for the images in the slider
//Because errors with movement is appeared
class BlockFour extends Component {

    render() {

        if (this.props.sliderElements) {
            const {sliderElements, width, config, selectConfig} = this.props;
            return (
                <div className="blockfive">
                    <div className="blockfive--inner">
                        <div className="blockfive__container">
                            <div className="blockfive__container__header">
                                <div className="blockfive__container__header__container">
                                    <h1>Application Gallery</h1>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
                                        A aliquid blanditiis consequuntur debitis deserunt eaque eligendi
                                    </p>
                                    <div className="blockfive__header--divider"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div className="blockfive__container__device">
                                <h2>
                                    Choose your device to what screenshots
                                </h2>
                                <ul className="tabs">
                                    {
                                            sliderElements.map(item =>
                                            <li
                                                key={item.id}
                                                className="tab"
                                                >
                                                <a href="#"
                                                   onClick={
                                                       () => selectConfig(item.id)
                                                   }
                                                >
                                                    {item.device}
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        )
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div className="blockfive__container__gallery">
                                {
                                        <Slider
                                        width={width}
                                        styles={sliderElements[config].styles}
                                        device_image={sliderElements[config].image}
                                    />
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return null
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({sliderElements, config}) => {
    return {
        sliderElements,
        config
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(appDesign(BlockFour));
```

So, this syntax is working, everything is loading and working. So, I have a question: What is the right way to fetch async data in AC, then pass them to reducer and then load inside the component. I don't want to use if statement inside my component.

I read couple of guides about async/await AC and how use them, but I do not completely understand how to use it in my situation. Could you please give me a brief direction how to implement it here. Thank you!

Comment: you make a request (fetch or whatever library you are going to use) in the callback of that request you have the data.. then you dispatch that data to the reducer

Comment: Thats pretty much what you're doing. No prob at all.

Comment: @WilomGfx It works, yes, but I read some guides, where people write three AC, that is DATA_IS_FETCHING, DATA_IS_FETCHED, and DATA_IS_LOADED. And I don't understand this approached, and should I use it here

Comment: @JohnRuddell I mean - should I use this approach (http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html) here or is this fine?

Comment: @Remzes i prefer DATA_IS_FETCHING , DATA_FETCHED AND DATA_FETCH_FAIL, thats all i need. To know when these 3 happen.

Comment: @Remzes yes essentially thats what i do. Its logical and enables to act accordingly in your UI and anywhere else.

Comment: @WilomGfx So, I need to use three dispatch functions inside my reducer?

Comment: @Remzes need no, should consider yes. And you will dispatching from your action creators and listening to them inside your reducer yes ;)

Comment: @WilomGfx so, I will add to my my state isFetching, isFetched, and will change them depends on the my loading progress. And then I will use it inside my component, so, if isFetched = true, I will load my component data, if isFetching=true, so, I will display "Data is Loading...". Is this approach right?

Comment: @Remzes something along those lines  yes!

Comment: @WilomGfx I got it, thank you!

Comment: no prob. I can put it in an answer so you can accept it and get this one closed.

Comment: @WilomGfx Great, thanks

Comment: @Remzes voila!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally and most people follow this [approach](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#actions). Its completely personal and wont change much in your app, but might make your life easier.

```
{ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_REQUEST' }
{ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_FAILURE', error: 'Oops' }
{ type: 'FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS', response: { ... } }
```

This way your UI and other parts of your app connected to the store can act accordingly depending on the state.

Exemples includes : showing a loading icon or message when `FETCH_SMTH_REQUEST` is fired and your state changes to fetching and showing an error when `FETCH_SMTH_FAILURE` and you get the `error` in your state.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use constants with the same name of the content, as a Type. Like this:

```js
export const Types = {
  FETCH_DATA_START: "FETCH_DATA_START",
  FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS: "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
  FETCH_DATA_FAIL: "FETCH_DATA_FAIL",
};
```

Just to be clear, I've hadn't seen nothing wrong and different of it in other projects that I've worked on. At least in my opinion, your action is great. I probably would wrap it all in a try...catch clause to have a best control of my flux of data.

Just to know, if you need, when you using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), you have the actual state as a second parameter and, if you need, you can pass extra arguments in the middleware configuration as the third parameter, like an API for exemple. So, your code, could seem like this:

```js
export const fetchMySpecialData = () => async(dispatch, getState, API) => {
  try {
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA_START"});    
    const data = await API.fetchData();
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS", payload: data});
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA_FAIL", error: err});
  }
};
```